# Does passing self in a nested function make sense?

Tags: python-3.x, function, nested, arguments, self

```
class Example:
       def outerExample(self, s):
              def innerExample(self, s):
                     print("hello " + s)
              innerExample(s)
a = Example()
a.outerExample("world")
```

When I use *self* as a parameter in the method *outerFunction*, I know that it is considered the instance *outerFunction* is called on. But does it make any sense when I use *self* in the nested *innerFunction*. Does Python consider the latter as just another argument?

Comment: Nested functions don't need the self argument.

Comment: Try it :) the code will fail because it's expecting two arguments in the call to innerExample. There is nothing special about self in python, it's by convention the name of the first argument in methods.

Comment: @RiccardoSvenRisuleo Thanks. I did try running the code and it fails. It's the `self` argument I was missing. But it does not need the self argument in the parameters anyway..